# A case of the central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

I want to show that

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^N X_k}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^N X_k^2}} \overset{N\to\infty}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0,1)\text{ in distribution,}$$

where $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of iid random variables with $\mathbb{E}(X_1)=0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_1^2) = s < \infty$.

Now I know about the CLT, i. e. $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^N X_k}{\sqrt{sn}}\to\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and about the proof with characteristic functions, but calculating the CF of this thing seems a bit cumbersome and I think I am missing a more elegant approach.

I would appreciate a hint. TIA

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{sn}$ and apply [Slutsky's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky's_theorem).

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you very much!

Comment: I thought of mentioning Slutsky's theorem; then I saw the comment above.  I'll add that all sorts of stuff (including Slutsky's theorem) is in Robert Serfling's book _Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics_.

Comment: @guy Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide numerator and denominator by $\sqrt {sn}$ and apply Slutsky's theorem. After the division, the numerator converges to an $\mathcal N(0, 1)$ while
$$
\sqrt{\sum X_i ^ 2 / sn} \to \sqrt{s / s} = 1,
$$
by the SLLN. By Slutsky's theorem the ratio converges to an $\mathcal N(0, 1)$ random variable.